# Unarmed Strikes while mounted

Tags: dnd-5e, mounted-combat

One of my players is a monk and currently the party is mounted. It seems according to the rules of mounted combat PHB p198 that there is no issue of needing a weapon or reach to attack from on a mount. Does that mean he could use unarmed strikes from on the horse? Could he even attack someone on the ground?

Comment: Note that the player could dismount and remount for a very limited amount of movement here without provoking an opportunity attack. So unless they're running across vast plains, that may be a reasonable part of the answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As far as the rules are concerned, yes, he can use unarmed strikes from the top of his horse. Just as you've noted, the Mounted Combat rules don't place any restrictions on how you can attack.

If you need help justifying this in-game, you can consider that an unarmed strike is defined as:

> a punch, kick,
>   head-butt, or similar forceful blow

So if it doesn't make sense to you that he could be punching creatures from the top of his horse, maybe he is kicking them instead?

Comment: One of my players had a creative solution: His monk did a partial dismount on one side of the horse while keeping hold of the reins, and then began drop-kicking the prone enemy. ^_^

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/vtZZM6P.jpg

Comment: @Pitzy that's also a very Kung Fu'ey visual. Another solution is to use a quarter staff or spear which are simple weapons and therefore count as "monk's weapons" for unarmed strikes.